# CSS image filling all screen having transparent elements in the middle of image

Tags: css, image, fullscreen

I have this situation using CSS.

I want an image to be in the center of the screen, doesn't matter the size of the screen, always in the middle. That's pretty easy to do.

But, the image (.png) I want to be in the middle is black and has some transparent letters in it.

So, I want the whole screen to be black, but still have transparent letters in the middle of the screen.

The reason I want transparent letters is because I'm using a script to fill the letters while the page is loading. The idea is based on a progress loading bar, but in this case, using letters as the 'bar'.

How can I achieve that? I have tried surrounding the image with divs but it's not the best way since depending on the screen size, some divs may not reach the image and left a blank space.

What do you suggest? What should I read?

Just in case I didn't make myself clear, here is an image:

[image: Help Image]

Comment: Transparent letters? You mean white letters?

Comment: No. I mean transparent letters. No color where the letters are, just transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I can currently think of, to black out the screen around the centered `img` is to use `box-shadow`:

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -250px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px #000;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WmS26/).

This does, of course, require that the browser supports the `box-shadow` property (or at least one of the vendor-prefixed implementations), and also takes a fairly arbitrary number for the 'spread' of the blur.

Unfortunately, while I'd rather use the `border` property the `border` affects the layout and must be compensated for in positioning the `img`, whereas the `box-shadow` doesn't affect the layout of the page.

With this demonstration, obviously, the `background-color` should be replaced by a `background-image` or whatever alternative you're using to represent the loading bar.

Comment: I can't see the image you put in the fiddle.

Comment: The big red letters? That's the `background-color` showing *through* the image. The background-colour *of* the image is black. I assumed you wanted the image to match the 'blacked out' look? (Change the `border-color` to another colour if not. =)

Comment: I don't know if I am allowed to say this here, but I love you David. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the whole screen black, but you have transparent letters that you want to be seen?

IF i understand what you want correctly, could you make the background color of the body (or html object) black, keep the image, but put a white (or colored) image directly behind the logo using absolute positioning.

I guess I don't understand why you want the transparent letters, but a black background.

Comment: The reason I want transparent letters is because I'm using a script to fill the letters while the page is loading. The idea is based on a progress loading bar, but in this case, using letters as the 'bar'.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?  I'm sure there is a better solution, but what about All black background with your logo in the middle, and then have a div placed behind the logo, and grow the div's width as the progress continues?

Comment: From top to bottom:
layer 1: an image with transparent letters.
layer 2: a div which fills itself with javascript and has a background-color of red, it fills like a whole screen progress bar. 

This will cause the effect of having the letters 'filling'.